# If statement doesn't block flow of events even though the code inside it is activated

Tags: javascript, node.js

The "if statement" in my code keeps doing a console.log which comes after the "if statement" even though the code inside it is calling the search function.

Is there any way I can prevent this?

```js
function search() {
  /**
   * The Tweet checking algorithm.
   * @private
   */
  function checkTweet(tweet) {
    if (tweet.favorite_count <= 5) {
      log('less than 5 likes');
      search();
    }
    if (getBlockedWords().includes(tweet.text)) {
      log('includes blocked words');
      search();
    }
    console.log(tweet);  // This line activates even though the if statements are calling the search function.
  }

  Twitter.get(
    'search/tweets',
    {q: getSearchKey(), count: 30, lang: 'en'},
    function(err, data, response) {
      let tweetList = [];
      if (!err) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.statuses.length; i++) {
          let tweet = data.statuses[i];
          tweetList.push(tweet);
        }
        var result = tweetList[Math.floor(Math.random() * tweetList.length)];
        checkTweet(result);
      } else {
        log(err);
        sleep(search);
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: It isn't really clear what or why you are asking this, but you could simply just remove the `console.log`.

Comment: Javascript is an asynchronous language now. There is, sadly, no going back to the procedural way. The engine will fight you constantly if you don't learn how to adapt. So things will happen concurrently all the time and you will have to think about avoiding race conditions (B coming before A) all the time.

Comment: @DrewReese it's not about the console logging every time, but I need the function to be called again recursively.

Comment: @raphtlw Like I said, if you don't want the console.log, remove it. If you want some other different behavior can you be a little clearer about what your desired result should be? Your search function fires off a bunch of asynchronous requests so JS happily keeps chugging along on the main thread continuing to process the rest of your function, which includes the console.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An if statement doesn't necessarily stop the flow of code.  An if statement runs *if* the condition evaluates as true.  Whether is continues running is dependent on the code within the if statement.

One simple way of accomplishing this is to simply use `return` within your if block.  This will prevent the rest of the code within that function from running.

```
function checkTweet(tweet) {
    if (tweet.favorite_count <= 5) {
      log('less than 5 likes');
      search();
      return;
    }
    if (getBlockedWords().includes(tweet.text)) {
      log('includes blocked words');
      search();
      return;
    }
    console.log(tweet);  // This line activates even though the if statements are calling the search function.
  }
```

Comment: The purpose of `return` is to "return" values from your code.  You can return any value or expression.  In the case that nothing is explicitly return, like the case in my example, you are actually returning `undefined`.